# spacemacs, anaconda, jedi/completion: Server error: ValueError('need more than 0 values to unpack',)

Tags: python, autocomplete, anaconda, jedi

my python (2.7.12) code is very simple

```
import os

os.<HERE>
```

instead of autocompletion I get following code:

`Server error: ValueError('need more than 0 values to unpack',)`

but, the following code gives me correct autocompletion.

```
import sys
sys.<HERE>
```

I'm running:

```
emacs-24.5
anaconda_mode-0.1.7
jedi-0.10.0.dist-info
service_factory-0.1.5.dist-info
```

regards,
Mat

Comment: I am having the same issue with emacs 25.1